# Error when trying to bind SelectedIndexChanged: No property, BindableProperty, or event found

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I have a picker inside an ObservableCollection, I need to bind the SelectedIndexChanged property with a custom command, since it will do some changes to the very same instance of object that contains this Picker and no outside this. I know the BindingContext is properly set, because the ItemsSource are loading as expected. But VS don't compiles and show this message:

`Binding SelectedIndexChanged: No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "SelectedIndexChanged", or mismatching type between value and property.`

This is how my code looks:

```
public event EventHandler HourChangedIndex
{
    add
    {
       HourChangedIndex += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
       {
           Hours.Add(((Picker)sender).SelectedItem as string);
           Hours = new ObservableCollection<string>(Hours.OrderBy(i => i));
        });
     }
     remove
     {
        HourChangedIndex -= new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            Hours.Add(((Picker)sender).SelectedItem as string);
            Hours = new ObservableCollection<string>(Hours.OrderBy(i => i));
        });
      }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` is an event handler, not a property, and can't be bound.  You can bind the `SelectedIndex` property or use `EventToCommand` behavior to translate the event into a command

Comment: But the SelectedIndex isn't to set/get the SelectedIndex? How can I know when it is changed?

Comment: check if the value is different in the setter

Comment: Ok, now I have understood it. Thank you @Jason

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection).
It describes the relationship between `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectedIndex` in detail.

> A Picker supports selection of one item at a time. When a user selects an item, the SelectedIndexChanged event fires, the SelectedIndex property is updated to an integer representing the index of the selected item in the list, and the SelectedItem property is updated to the object representing the selected item. The SelectedIndex property is a zero-based number indicating the item the user selected. If no item is selected, which is the case when the Picker is first created and initialized, SelectedIndex will be -1.